# Select a vertex if the edge to the vertex has a property value, otherwise choose another vertex with a different edge property value

Tags: c#, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am trying to grab vertices connecting a **Request** vertex to each **Card** vertex. The card-to-request relationship is one-to-many (each card has many requests).

A card may be connected to a request with the property `"Status"`: `"In Use"` if the card is being used. Each card will also be connected to many requests with the properties `"Status"`: `"Future Use"` or `"Past Use"`.

I am trying to create a table that displays the most recent use of each card.

Thus, I want to return a request if the edge connecting it to the card has the property `"Status"`: `"In Use"`.

If the card is not currently in use, I look for the request that most recently used the card (`"Status"`: `"Past Use"`).

If the card has never been used, I look for the soonest upcoming request that will use the card (`"Status"`: `"Future Use"`).

I have attempted to use `coalesce`:

```
.coalesce(
 select('request')
  .outE().hasLabel('AssignedTo}').has('Status', 'In Use'),
 select('request')
  .outE().hasLabel('AssignedTo').has('Status', 'Past Use').order().by('Timestamp', decr).limit(1),
 select('request')
  .outE().hasLabel('AssignedTo').has('Status', 'Future Use').order().by('Timestamp', incr).limit(1)
).as('status')
```

But this only returns a single record (In Use). Another version:

```
.coalesce(
 select('card')
  .inE().hasLabel('AssignedTo}').has('Status', 'In Use'),
 select('card')
  .inE().hasLabel('AssignedTo').has('Status', 'Past Use').order().by('Timestamp', decr).limit(1),
 select('card')
  .inE().hasLabel('AssignedTo').has('Status', 'Future Use').order().by('Timestamp', incr).limit(1)
).as('status')
```

This only returned two records (both In Use).

I tried `choose` awhile ago and couldn't get that to work either (don't recall what happened exactly).

**Expected:**

Get back a single vertex that has an edge with the property `"Status"`: `"In Use"`.

If this edge doesn't exist, get the most recent vertex that has an edge with the property `"Status"`: `"Past Use"`.

If there are no edges that qualify, get the soonest upcoming vertex that has an edge with the property `"Status"`: `"Future Use"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what went wrong with your query since you didn't post it entirely, but this should work:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Card").as("c").coalesce(
    outE("assigned").has("status", "In Use"),
    outE("assigned").has("status", "Past Use").order().by("Timestamp", desc).limit(1),
    outE("assigned").has("status", "Future Use").order().by("Timestamp", asc).limit(1),
).as("s").inV().as("r")
.select("c","s","r").by("name").by("status").by("name")
```